# what is the ref number in a github repository referring to?

Tags: git, github, terraform

I have a terraform file that references a provider's github repository. The config in terraform looks like this:

```
module "super-cool-module" {
  source = "git@github.com:provider_name/repo.git?ref=1234567890abc"
}
```

What is that `ref=1234567890abc` referring to? And how do I find that in their repository?

Comment: Likely a commit hash

Comment: i see, what is the reason why someone would want to use only a specific commit? Shouldn't the master branch always be up-to-date?

Comment: Sure but what if their default branch changes and breaks stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#selecting-a-revision):

> By default, Terraform will clone and use the default branch
> (referenced by HEAD) in the selected repository. You can override this
> using the ref argument. The value of the ref argument can be any
> reference that would be accepted by the git checkout command, such as
> branch, SHA-1 hash (short or full), or tag names. For a full list of
> the possible values, see [Git Tools - Revision Selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_single_revisions) in the Git
> Book.

So for example

```
module "super-cool-module" {
  source = "git@github.com:provider_name/repo.git?ref=v1.2.3"
}
```

Would refer to a git tag, while `1234567890abc` in

```
module "super-cool-module" {
  source = "git@github.com:provider_name/repo.git?ref=1234567890abc"
}
```

Refers to a commit as [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) mentioned.

And these parameters allow us to consume modules at a specific state of the repository, you can be using modules from a different repository maintained by a different team which continues merging to the main/master branch and you don't want that to affect your Terraform state or our infrastructure, as it makes more sense to adapt your IaC modules manually to avoid any breaking changes, so locking the version or the commit is generally a good idea.